# How to use a HashSet in my LINQ query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, hashset

I have a query for all users that looks like this:

```
from
    u in db.AspNetUsers
orderby
    u.UserName
select
    ....
```

That works fine. But now I want to filter for a specific user role. There is a `u.AspNetRoles` that is a HashSet of objects. Each object has a `Name` property that is the name of the role.

So I only want to select users who have a role object with `Name` equal to `"SuperAdmin"`.

Previously I just tried to join on the tables with the role data but that didn't work because there is an AspNetUserRoles table that only has a UserID and a RoleID with no primary key. And supposedly it's not recommended to make an entity class for a table that doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: Just to be clear:  You want to find only users that are in the role "SuperAdmin", right?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you are asking:

```
from
    u in db.AspNetUsers
where
    u.AspNetRoles.Any(r => r.Name == "SuperAdmin")
orderby
    u.UserName
select
    . . .
```

The `Any` method will return true if any of the items in the collection meet the criterion lambda (`r => r.Name == "SuperAdmin"`, in this case).  If any items in the collection `AspNetRoles` of user object `u` has a `Name` where the value is `"SuperAdmin"`, then the result of `Any` is true.  If none of the items meet the criterion, the `Any` returns false.